# Sums and products of random variables - Expected value

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value

Suppose your time of travel is 50 minutes and your train is delayed. You also have waiting times at three traffic lights.

Thus, the total time of travel is $W = 50 + B \cdot V + \sum_{i=1}^{3} B_i \cdot A_i$.

All random variables $B, B_1, B_2, B_3, A_1, A_2, A_3, V$ are independent.

We have $B \sim Binomial(1, \frac{1}{10})$, $B_1, B_2, B_3 \sim Binomial(1, \frac{1}{2})$, $A_1, A_2, A_3 \sim Uniform([0, 5])$, $V \sim Exponential(\frac{1}{10})$.

How does one now calculate the expected value $\mathbb{E}(W)$?

$\mathbb{E}(W) = \mathbb{E}(50+B \cdot V + B_1 \cdot A_1 + B_2 \cdot A_2 + B_3 \cdot A_3)$.

Comment: For independent random variables the expected value of their product is the product of their expected values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guide:

Ingredients that you need are

- Expectations are linear, that is the expecation of the sum is equal to the sum of the expectation$$\mathbb{E}(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}( X_i).$$
- Also, use the property that the random variables are independent. For example, $$\mathbb{E}(BV)=\mathbb{E} (B) \mathbb{E}(V).$$

You should be then be able to compute the expectation of each random variable and evaluate them.

Comment: So, we have $\mathbb{E}(W) = 50 + \mathbb{E}(B) \mathbb{E}(V) + \sum_{i=1}^3\mathbb{E}( B_i)\mathbb{E}( A_i)$. We also know the expected value of a binomial distribution is $np$, of a exponential distrbution it is $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ and of a continuous uniform distribution it is $\frac{1}{2}(a+b).$ Thus, we have $\mathbb{E}(W) = 50 + \frac{1}{10} \cdot 10 + (\frac{5}{4} + \frac{5}{4}+ \frac{5}{4})  = 50 + 1 + \frac{15}{4} = \frac{219}{4} = 54.75$. Correct?

Comment: Your working seems fine.